# Is it OK to use def main() with a pass statement in it for python module

Tags: python

I have a python script that I am using purely as a module. It has one class and a few other functions that are being imported to another python script using:

```
from module import *
```

The module looks something like this:

```
class myClass:

     def __init__(self, something):

     def someGetter(self):
         return whatever

     def someSetter(self):

def someSupportingFunction():
     return whatever

def someOtherSupportingFunction():
     return whatever


def main():
     pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

The script that I am using makes use of both the class and other functions included in the script.

Would this be a reasonable way to implement a module that does not need to be used via the command line? If not, what would be the best way to implement it?

From what I have read, doing a wildcard import using * is frowned upon. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you defining something called `main` at all if it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Well, you make a good point. I guess thats what I was essentially asking. So basically there is no need for it unless you want to be able to use the module via the command line right?

Comment: Yes `from module import *` is bad practice. If you need just 1 or 2 functions from there only import those instead of  `*`. And if you need a lot of stuff from there, prefer defining a shortcut for your module, like `import module as M` and then use `M.some_function(...)`.

Comment: @rasterops: Even if you do, there's no particular necessity to define a function called `main`.  You can call it anything you want.  You can even put code directly in the `if __name__=="__main__"` block, which is a bit sloppy but sometimes useful for short scripts.  Defining a function called `main` and calling it from an `if __name__` block are just conventions for how to a certain thing, namely define the behavior for when a module is run as a script.  If you don't need such behavior, there's no need to do those things.

Comment: @JulienBernu: So in my case where every function is being used in the module, it is a necessity and reasonable to do a wildcard import? I can understand where it might not be because if you are importing everything and not using it, it would simply be a waste of system resources right?

Comment: The main reason is because it is ambiguous and unsafe. Imagine someone else (or yourself in a few months) going through the code and seeing some undefined names. They'd have to go through all the modules to find where it comes from. Even worse, imagine you import two modules with `*` and both have a `my_func()` defined. When you then use `my_func()` in your script how do you know which module it comes from?

Comment: Great! Thanks to everybody for the clear and concise answers. I have accepted BrenBarn's answer and up voted JulienBernus comments that address importing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need a main function, don't define one and don't call it.  There's no requirement to have a function called `main`, and if you do define one, it has no special status and won't be called unless you call it yourself.

Just remove the last five lines of your code (the `def main` and the `if __name__...`).

Answer (score 1):

The main method and global variable **name** are optional. The python interpreter will not complain if it is not there.

```
def main():
     pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

**So what is `__name__`?** 
The global variable, `__name__`, in a `*.py` python file defines the entry point to your program. If it is there and when you are executing "this file" as your main python program then whatever logic that is in the if clause `__name__ == '__main__'` will be executed, otherwise it is ignored.

Hence it doesn't matter whether that piece of code is there or not since it is suppose to be just a class structure.